# How to make multiple calls asychronously to same api but with different params - node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I have developed a web service which is receiving queue of messages through RabbitMq. This message contains `userid` which has to be passed as query string to a third-party api.

Example of third-party api :
(eg: "https://api.example.com/user?userId='')

Web service has to call the api with userId received through message queue. Probably the service receives N number of messages within a second.

I Need best possible way to accomplish the scenario given above.My approach is as follows:

Push the `userid` into an array.
Iterate through the `userid` using `array.map()` method by passing api call as callback param.
Once the api response is received for an element, remove the element from array using `array.shift()` method.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: you can use `promises`. Make an array and push the promises of the request into it. Then use `Promise.all`.

Comment: A little code might help to understand what you are trying to do. It’s not clear reading this why you need a queue rather than doing the work in the callback to the third party api.

Comment: @Mark_M Queue of messages containing the userid is pushed to my web service from different service.